# Terraform with tflint in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

I've found some issues with tflint parsing some values when I try to access data in some maps.

First of all, I create `aws_health_check` with `count` set to 2.

Then, I create `aws_dns` record, with same `count`. And try to get `aws_health_check` ID this way:

```
    health_check_id = "${aws_route53_health_check.aws_health_check[count.index].id}"
```

tflint thinks it's not a valid way.

[image: tflint error]

So, how can I reconfigure tflint in VSCcode, or how can I access this data different way?